# Making every second letter in a string uppercase with a method other than index() in Python?

Tags: python

```
def myfunc(mylist = str):
mystring = ''
for x in mylist:
    if mylist.index(x) % 2 == 0:
        mystring = mystring + x.lower()
    else:
        mystring = mystring + x.upper()
return mystring
print(myfunc('committee')) #Doesn't work
print(myfunc('ilovehoney')) #Does work
```

I believe the mistake in my code is the index() since it does not recognize repeating letters in the string. Does anyone know of a different method I could use? The output in the first example is 'cOmmiTTEE' but should be 'cOmMiTtEe' while the output in the second example is as I intended 'iLoVeHoNeY'. Though I am not sure why my function suddenly works in the second example. Thanks for the help.

Comment: .index() searches for the FIRST match of x. So if you have reoccuring characters your current function will not work. Try: "eeeeeeeee" for example.

Comment: I see, so Index isn't a good choice for reoccuring characters, got it. Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `enumerate` to get the index and value from an iterable:

```
for idx, x in enumerate(mylist):
    if idx % 2 == 0:
        mystring = mystring + x.lower()
    else:
        mystring = mystring + x.upper()
```

Comment: That worked, thank you for your help.
Now time for me to find out what enumerate does and how multiple variables in a for loop work.
Unfortunately I don't have 15 reputation, which is why I cannot upvote your answer but I will once I will get the reputation.

Comment: @MMOToaster Basically, enumerate returns a tuple `(index, value)` for each item in the list which gets unpacked to `idx, x` in the code I shared with you. You can read more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate

Comment: The link in the above post may be a bit dense, actually. Try this one: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/

Comment: Ah, I see. Haven't quite understood what you just wrote but I'll look up the link you posted, thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I will read both of them and try to understand them.

Answer (score 3):

enumerate() gives you the index of the current loop:

```
s = 'committee'
"".join([x.upper() if i%2!=0 else x for i,x in enumerate(s)])
Out[4]: 'cOmMiTtEe'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not too familiar with list comprehension unfortunately, which is why I try to avoid it for now but thank you what you wrote looks really interesting. Unfortunately I don't have 15 reputation, which is why I cannot upvote your answer but I will once I will get the reputation.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know the exact index at all. Just flip a flag: no-yes-no-yes-no-etc.

```
def myfunc(mylist):
    mystring = ''
    upper = False
    for x in mylist:
        mystring = mystring + (x.upper() if upper else x.lower())
        upper = not upper
    return mystring
```

Please note that it is inefficient to construct a string that way (give "Shlemiel the painter" to google). Improved version:

```
def myfunc(mylist):
    mychars = []
    upper = False
    for x in mylist:
        mychars.append(x.upper() if upper else x.lower())
        upper = not upper
    return ''.join(mychars)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That no-yes-no-yes routine seems like the simplest way of solving a flip flag task. I think I will use that from now on for future similar tasks, thank you. Though I do not understand why the first code is inefficient, I will give 'Shlemiel the painter' thing a read. Unfortunately I don't have 15 reputation, which is why I cannot upvote your answer but I will once I will get the reputation.

Comment: I'm glad I could help a little bit. Don't worry about upvotes.